# How to switch into desktop mode

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I have a Nexus 4 with Ubuntu Touch. It is now updated to OTA12.

I wonder, because if I connect the device via a Slimportad adapter to my external screen, it does not switch into convergence mode. The screen of the Nexus 4 can be used as keyboard and mouse touch pad. And at the big screen I can see the mousepointer and the normal screen layout as I am used to see on the screen of my Nexus 4.

I remember at OTA10, Ubuntu Touch switched on the desktop mode automatically, if conected to an external screen. In desktop mode I should see normally windows with titlebar and all all apps are running at the same time.

I know some Aquaris devices do have an build in switch at the System-Notification-Tab. But at the Nexus 4 there is not such a switch.

I even did a full reset of Ubuntu Touch. But this did not solve the problem.

How do I switch into desktop mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, from the terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Windowed
```

To go back:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Staged
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to install the "UT Tweak Tool" from the "OpenStore" and select in the "Usage Mode" Tab "Windowed". Then you have a windowed user interface. That's not a nice solution because it should switch automatically, but the tool also offers cool other features.

Comment: Do I understand right, normally it should switch automatically, even if I am running ota12?

Comment: Well, I don't exactly, I think it should. But the autoswitching also doesn't seem to work with my device, hwen I connect a Keyboard/Mouse with it. I must witch it manually too.

Comment: I have just connected my Bluetooth devices and my phone has not switched automatically. I am sure that it did before the latest update. This seems lile it could be a bug and worth loggong in Launchpad.

Comment: Yes, even after a full reset of my device, I can't get into desktop mode. Do you know where to post my bug at launchpad?

Comment: I have always had a problem trying to find the correct place to post bungs in Launchpad. If i was posting it I would add it under system. It will be moved if it is wrong.

Comment: Here is where you would report such a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+filebug

Answer (score 0):

I had some emails with the Ubuntu Phone Team: [MailingList](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg22013.html)

Pat McGowan did an awesome prescription about how Ubuntu Touch handles the Desktop Mode. Here is an excerpt of his answer:

"The latest logic switches to Windowed mode when a mouse or touchpad is
available (not based on having an external monitor), so your Nexus 4 should
switch because its acting as the pointer.  However it also checks that the
width of the screen is at least 60 grid units, which in this case is only
1080 pixels. I believe there is similar logic to decide whether to display
the Desktop mode toggle in the session indicator based on screen width."

My problem was, that the resolution of the external screen was not detected properly.

I filed now a bug to improve the user experience regarding the possibilities to use the desktop mode. The Link goes [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1625365). Every one who likes my proposal is welcome to click to "This bug affects you" to add more bug heat.