# Set bq Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition to staged mode permanently

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, aquaris, m10

Running `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode 'Staged'` it only works until I block the screen and reconnect the device.

I want to set it up permanently.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Staged mode should be the norm. Are you doing something else which would force the device into Windowed mode? Maybe keeping a keyboard or mouse connected?

From other threads the best advice seems to be to install UT Tweak Tool from the OpenStore and to set your desired mode that way.

To install OpenStore:

1. Download the [OpenStore](https://open.uappexplorer.com/api/download/openstore.openstore-team/openstore.openstore-team_0.103_armhf.click)
2. Open the terminal app
3. Navigate to the downloads folder
4. Run the command `pkcon install-local --allow-untrusted openstore.openstore-team_0.103_armhf.click`

Once you have that done search for and install the UT Tweak Tool. That tool should have a tab called 'Usage Mode' which allows you to choose between Windowed and Staged.

References;
[How to switch into desktop mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804409/how-to-switch-into-desktop-mode/846751)

Comment: Sorry. Perhaps I haven't been clear enough.

I know how to change between _staged mode_ and _windowed mode_ but when I connect a keyboard it automatically switches to _windowed mode_, even if I've run `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode 'Staged'`.

I want it to be always in 'staged mode' even if I connect a keyboard. :-(

Comment: Sure, I understand.

I thought that using the UT tweak tool might help keep the setting fixed.

Perhaps the best place to ask this would be on the Ubuntu-phone mailing list, in response to this email. [https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg22013.html]